# get the return value of method using annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I am new to annotation processor, I wonder if it is possible to get the the return value of a method marked with annotations during annotation processing. For example, I have annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Parameters {}
```

and I have a class marked with this annotation:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 2 }
    });
}
```

is it possible I get `new Object[][] { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 2 } }`  using annotation processing tool(apt)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can **invoke** your method with [reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation) by filtering on the list of methods available in your class and annotated with your **custom annotation**. Your code will look something like this:

```
Object[][] objectArray; // should be initialize
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Parameters.class)) {
        objectArray = method.invoke(object);
    }
}

return objectArray;
```

Where `object` is an instance of your class containing the your method.

Comment: is it possible to use annotation processor tool(apt)?

Comment: Yes it is possible to use apt. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html#:~:text=The%20apt%20tool%20is%20a,only%20view%20of%20program%20structure.